# Recommendations on runsettings file for connection string override

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, devops, runsettings

I have several tests projects in C# that use Database to perform tests. I'd like to create a runsettings file in order to override connection string to this DB at test execution time when using Azure DevOps.

I have not succeeded in writing the runsettings file properly yet.

Do you have any tips or recommendations on how to do that?

Comment: Where are your connectionString? In the `App.config` file?

Comment: @FelipeOriani yes in my app.config file

Answer (score 2):

You could transform your configuration file. For sample, if you have a app.config file that store a connectionstring to perform the tests, you could replace this connectionString with a valid database and run the tests.

There is a build step called `Config Transformation` and you can add it on the Azure DevOps pipeline. Actually, I use this build step when I am releasing application to different environments (so we replace the settings and connectionStrings with appropriated values). You can use it on the build pipeline.

Let's supose you have the `app.config` file, so, you could create an file where the variables are, for sample `app.tests.config`, and define it on the `Config Transformation` step, for sample:

[image]

It is based on the transformation for config files. Take a look at this like to know how to configure it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations

I am not sure about your scenario but if you are using Unit Tests the best way to perform it is to use Mocks/Stubs (to simulate the database) instead accessing database.